# Known issue with expression bodies in properties?

Tags: c#, uwp, resharper, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I'm facing a problem with the latest ReSharper version using Visual Studio 2017 RC.

The Editor of ReSharper tells me it can't resolve symbols like var or tokens like public or void are not expected etc. pp.

Not sure but it turns out that expression bodies used in properties are the root cause.

Example:

```
public double PlayingProgress
{
    get => _playingProgress;
    set => SetProperty(ref _playingProgress, value);
}
```

If using normal brackets instead of the expression body ReSharper seems like to have no problems anymore as the red marked area goes away.

Is this a known problem, or are there other things known as cause?

Is there a known workaround (I already tried to clear the cache and dis/enable ReSharper)?

Would be shitty if this new C# 7.0 feature won't work with ReSharper.

Comment: Shouldn't that be filed as an issue to Resharper? If VS2017 accepts and compiles the code, it's a ReSharper bug. Perhaps, there already is an EAP that fixes this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ReSharper 2016.3 has been released quite recently. I wouldn't expect a new EAP anytime soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/12/15/resharper-ultimate-2016-3-is-released/), the latest version of ReSharper (2016.3) has "**early support** for C# 7" (emphasis mine). This means that not all C# 7 features are going to work right now (the post explicitly mentions some features that are supported, but does not mention expression-bodied getters and setters). Presumably this will be fixed in a later version, possibly the one released when the RTM version of VS 2017 is released.

Considering that C# 7 is still being developed, I don't think you should expect full support from tools like ReSharper.

Comment: Exactly this. Despite shipping in a "release candidate" version of VS2017, C# 7.0 hasn't yet been signed off (and there are mentions of breaking changes for RC2/3, too, even though the first RC has a go-live license). ReSharper has C# 7.0 support planned for the 2017.1 release. Expect it around the time VS2017 hits RTM.

Comment: Okay, then I just have to wait more until release.
And is 7.0 not finished? Thought all features are done already that will be shipped.

Comment: @klose91 As far as I know, all C# 7 features are already implemented, but their details may still change.